# Как обновить несколько значений в строке базы Postgres с помощью C#?

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net, entity-framework

Нужно обновить несколько значений в строке базы, но как это сделать - не понятно.

```
public void Update(int id, Tutor tutor)
{
    var tutors = applicationContext.Tutors
        .Where(x => x.Id == id)
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(_ => new Tutor {
            Id = tutor.Id,
            FirstName = tutor.FirstName,
            Educations = tutor.Educations,
            Awards = tutor.Awards
        });

    foreach (var t in tutors) applicationContext.Entry(t).State = EntityState.Modified;
    applicationContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Изначально не известно какие строки будут изменены и я пока не знаю как их передавать в метод `Update`, так как у них разные типы. Единственное, что придумал - это передавать весь объект `tutor`, который был изменен где-то заранее, что, во-первых, выглядит, что сделано не правильно, во-вторых, метод еще и не работает. Появляется ошибка:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actua
lly affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkI
d=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.
```

Comment: [Identity Resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/identity-resolution) - ответ здесь, несколько вариантов. Пока ссылка, потом отвечу подробно, если ещё будет нужно.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov получается я могу передавать в метод `Update` id и словарь с ключом (названием столбца в таблице) и значением (новым значением в столбце), находить строку по id и проходить по словарю изменяя значения?

Comment: Вообще вариант не плохой, но нужно как-то добавить типизацию, чтобы не те данные не ввести.  
Еще можно в сигнатуре метода определить поля из `tutor` со значением по умолчанию null и в методе смотреть, если значение не null, то изменять его, но в таком случае, если я захочу изменить значение поля на null, то изменения не произойдет

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В вашем методе `Update` происходит что-то странное. Извлекаются сущности по `id`, а т. к. это явно первичный ключ, то такой объект может быть всего один.

Судя по исключению, параметр `id` не равен свойству `tutor.Id`, поэтому из БД извлекается и трекается одна сущность, а модифицированной помечается другая.

Ладно, забудем этот метод и посмотрим в документации, какие есть способы обновления сущностей: [Identity Resolution in EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/identity-resolution).

---

### Используем метод `Update` контекста.

Он начинает отслеживать (трекать) сущность и всё дерево её свойств.

```
void Update(Tutor tutor)
{
    using var context = new AppContext();
    context.Update(tutor);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Достоинство:** выполняется всего один запрос в БД на обновление.
**Недостаток:** в БД будут обновлены все свойства, даже если они не менялись у сущности. Это может быть неприемлемо, если в БД имеются триггеры на обновление некоторых колонок.

---

### Выполняем запрос, затем применяем изменения.

```
void Update(Tutor tutor)
{
    using var context = new AppContext();
    var trackedTutor = context.Tutors.Find(tutor.Id);

    trackedTutor.FirstName = tutor.FirstName;
    trackedTutor.LastName = tutor.LastName;

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Достоинство:** в БД обновляются только действительно изменённые свойства.
**Недостаток:** выполняются два запроса в БД (select и update), что весьма дорого. При этом из БД будут извлекаться все свойства сущности, а некоторые из них могут быть большими бинарными (например, содержит изображение-аватарку).

EF Core имеет развитые средства для работы с сущностями. Например, вместо ручного задания всех свойств можно использовать метод `PropertyValues.SetValues`. Получается встроенный аналог авто-маппера. Весьма удобно.

```
void Update(Tutor tutor)
{
    using var context = new AppContext();
    var trackedTutor = context.Tutors.Find(tutor.Id);

    context.Entry(trackedTutor).CurrentValues.SetValues(tutor);

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Вместо сущности можно использовать любой объект (DTO) с совпадающими свойствами. Или даже словарь! Примеры смотрите в документации.

---

### Используем исходные значения.

Метод `Attach` начинает отслеживать сущность в состоянии `Unchanged` (неизменённая). И когда мы задаём оригинальные значения, то те из них, которые отличаются, помечаются за модифицированные. И sql-запрос в БД будет содержать только эти колонки.

В документации приведён пример со словарём, но можно использовать и сущность. Главное, правильно (де)сериализовать.

```
void Update(Tutor modifiedTutor, Tutor originalTutor)
{
    using var context = new AppContext();

    context.Attach(modifiedTutor);
    context.Entry(modifiedTutor).OriginalValues.SetValues(originalTutor);

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Для использования этого варианта, например, в ASP.NET, нужно передавать на html-страницу оригинальные значения в скрытых полях (hidden input).

**Достоинства:** выполняется всего один запрос в БД, обновляются только изменённые свойства.
**Недостатки:** нужно передавать с сервера на клиент и обратно оригинальные значения (в скрытых полях или как-то ещё). Таким образом мы уменьшаем нагрузку на БД, но увеличиваем нагрузку на сеть. Это может быть как дешевле, так и дороже передачи лишних данных из/в БД.

---

Осталось выбрать из этих трёх способов наиболее подходящий.