# Не сохраняются данные в БД SQLite

Tags: c#, .net

Не сохраняются данные в БД после выполнения этого кода:

```
using (db = new AppContext()){
     curUser.PlayerFive = 0;
     await db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

В debug всё нормально, но когда я запрашиваю curUser.PlayerFive, то оно остаётся как было.

Comment: Объект `curUser` не отслеживается (не трекается) контекстом `db`. Поэтому не сохраняется.

Comment: Однозначно. Нужно сначала запросить этого `curUser` из текущего контекста. Например, по `Id`, если он у него есть.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Решил тем, что сначала запросил curUser.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1465109/184217