# Проблема при обновлении сущности в EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Я пытаюсь обновить сущность в репозитории, но у меня возникает ошибка:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 
'CatalogItem' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same 
key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing 
entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value 
is attached. Consider using '

DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.
```

Как её исправить?

Обновление происходит следующим образом:

```
public async Task UpdateAsync(CatalogItemUpdateParameters parameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var catalogItem = await _catalogItemRepository.FirstOrDefaultAsync(parameters.Id, cancellationToken) ??
                    throw new ObjectNotFoundException($"Элемент каталога с Id {parameters.Id} не найден");

    catalogItem.Name = parameters.Name;
    catalogItem.UpdatedAtUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;

    await _catalogItemModelValidator.ValidateAndThrowAsync(catalogItem, cancellationToken);

    await _catalogItemRepository.UpdateAsync(catalogItem, cancellationToken);
}

public Task UpdateAsync(TModel model, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var entity = _mapper.Map<TEntity>(model);
    
    _dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Update(entity);

    return _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

Comment: А где вы такой код обновления подсмотрели? И что вы вообще хотите поменять у `catalogItem` собственно? Схема должна быть простая: 1) прочитали сущность 2) поменяли в ней что-то, какие-то поля 3) сделали `SaveChanges`, а вот эти все шаманства непонятные со `State` и все прочие - они не нужны и даже вредны. Что вы маппером делаете, например? Я так понимаю, при этом создаётся новая сущность, которую база не трекает. Но ключ у неё тот же, что уже у имеющейся сущности. Для добавления новой сущности есть `Add`. Не надо вот этих шаманств непонятных.

Comment: Метод [DbSet<TEntity>.Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.update?view=efcore-7.0) - **Начинает отслеживание** заданной сущности. Между тем эта сущность уже содержится в DbContext'е.  `_dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Update(entity);` - эта строка не нужна.

Comment: М-м-м... Насколько я могу судить, в первом методе `UpdateAsync(CatalogItemUpdateParameters parameters` не следует вызывать второй. Следует заменить последнюю строку на `_dbContext.SaveChangesAsync`.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1465109/184217 - Есть несколько способов выполнить Update в EF.

Comment: Вот ещё что. В одном методе вы используете репозиторий `_catalogItemRepository`, в другом напрямую обращаетесь к `_dbContext`. Вы уж определитесь: если вы внедрили в свой проект репозиторий, то всегда работайте через него. Или полностью его выкиньте и всегда работайте с контекстом.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте записать получение объекта из БД, вот так
var catalogItem = await _catalogItemRepository.FirstOrDefaultAsync(parameters.Id, cancellationToken).AsNoTracking() ??
throw new ObjectNotFoundException($"Элемент каталога с Id {parameters.Id} не найден");

Имеется в виду что данный объект извлекатся из базы данных без отслеживания, то есть с опцией.AsNoTracking()

Comment: В принципе, отключение трекинга поможет решить данную конкретную проблему автора. / Конечно, показанным способом этот метод вызвать не удастся, но это мелочи.