# Обновление сущности

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

В рабочем проекте используется следующий метод обновления сущности через EF Core

```
    public virtual async Task<int> UpdateAsync(TDto item, CancellationToken token)
    {
        var existingEntity = await dbSet
            .AsNoTracking()
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == item.Id, token)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (existingEntity is null)
            return ICrudRepository<TDto>.ErrorIdNotFound;

        var entity = Convert(item);
        var entry = dbSet.Update(entity);
        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(token);
        entry.State = EntityState.Detached;
        return entry.Entity.Id;
    }
```

Если я пытаюсь обновить имя сущности на такое же, которое у неё уже установлено, то получаю исключение

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'ManualFolder' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.
```

С чем это может быть связано?

```
public async Task UpdateFolderAsync(int id, string name, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var folder = await manualFolderRepository.GetOrDefaultAsync(id, cancellationToken)
                ?? throw new ArgumentInvalidException($"Папки с Id: {id} не сущесвует", nameof(id));

    folder.Name = name;

    if (await IsExistFolderAsync(folder, cancellationToken))
        throw new ArgumentInvalidException("Папка с таким названием уже существует", name);

    await manualFolderRepository.UpdateAsync(folder, cancellationToken);
}
```

Когда я пытаюсь обновить папку и именем "ТЕСТ" на "ТЕСТ", то получаю это исключение. Если я пытаюсь обновить на "ТЕСТ1" всё норм

Comment: В вашем собственном методе `UpdateAsync` используется `AsNoTracking` и далее `dbSet.Update`. При этом проблем не должно быть. Значит, сущность добавляется в контекст где-то в другом месте. Смотрите (и нам можете показать) методы `manualFolderRepository.GetOrDefaultAsync` и `IsExistFolderAsync`.

Comment: У вас производятся две одинаковые, на мой взгляд проверки: сперва `IsExistFolderAsync`, а затем проверка `existingEntity`. Что-то тут лишнее.

Comment: Есть несколько способов выполнить Update: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1465109/184217

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка, которую вы видите, связана с тем, что EF Core пытается отслеживать два разных экземпляра сущности с одинаковым ключом. В вашем коде это происходит из-за следующей последовательности действий:

Вы извлекаете сущность из базы данных с помощью manualFolderRepository.GetOrDefaultAsync(id, cancellationToken). Этот метод, вероятно, возвращает отслеживаемую сущность (т.е. сущность, которая находится в состоянии EntityState.Unchanged).

Затем вы пытаетесь обновить эту сущность с помощью manualFolderRepository.UpdateAsync(folder, cancellationToken). Внутри этого метода вы извлекаете другой экземпляр этой же сущности с помощью AsNoTracking(), что означает, что этот экземпляр не отслеживается.

После этого вы пытаетесь обновить сущность с помощью dbSet.Update(entity), но EF Core видит, что уже отслеживает другой экземпляр этой сущности (тот, который вы извлекли в шаге 1), и выдает ошибку.

Чтобы решить эту проблему, вы можете выполнить одно из следующих действий:

1. Отключить отслеживание при первом извлечении: Измените метод GetOrDefaultAsync так, чтобы он использовал AsNoTracking(), если вы не планируете вносить изменения в этот экземпляр сущности.
2. Используйте один и тот же экземпляр сущности: Вместо того чтобы извлекать новый экземпляр сущности в методе UpdateAsync, используйте экземпляр, который вы передали в этот метод, и обновите его.
3. Явно отсоедините сущность перед обновлением: Перед вызовом UpdateAsync вы можете явно отсоединить сущность от контекста:

   dbContext.Entry(folder).State = EntityState.Detached;
   await manualFolderRepository.UpdateAsync(folder, cancellationToken);

Любой из этих подходов должен решить вашу проблему. Выберите тот, который наилучшим образом соответствует вашим потребностям и структуре кода.

Comment: Автор уже использует `AsNoTracking`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov он сначала получает сущность и там я не вижу нигде `AsNoTracking`. `AsNoTracking ` есть в самом `Update` - но там так же учавствует уже вытянутая запись