# SaveChangesAsync и entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Пытаюсь использовать конструкцию

```
 entityDbSet.Update(entity);
    var dbContext = entityDbSet.GetDbContext();
    await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
```

модель

```
    public class entity 
{        
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
}
```

Если я передаю данные например id=1;Name="Petr" то поле ShortName становится null...Почему он обнуляет поля которые не переданы в модели??

Comment: Покажите код до `Update`, как добавляете объект в changetracker. Есть моменты, когда это работает так, как вы описываете, но надо убедиться, что вы делаете именно так, как я думаю

Comment: В EF есть три основных способа обновления сущностей. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1465109/184217 - здесь с моими комментариями.